Communication does not occur when connecting an LED to the UART line
I attached LEDs using transistors to UART RX and TX as shown in the attached photo.
But the led doesn't work and the uart doesn't work either.
If I remove this circuit the uart works fine
What's the problem?


The problem is not in the parts of the circuit you show. Or if it is, the other circuit you are connecting to is unknown. Please add more details.

@Justme - Other circuit parts are just rx and tx connected.

Try changing R7 and R8 to 10k or more. You may be overloading the RXD and TXD signals.

@bomdong2230 Yeah I get that, but where are they connected? To which UART? MCU? PC? Arduino? RS-232 or logic level? 5V or 1.2V level? What are the parameters of the things that connect to the TXD and RXD?

@Justme - It is directly connected to esp32

@bomdong2230 Well it should work. Unless what you really have does not match the schematics. In which case the problem isn't the schematics but what you really have.

As Dave already suggested, change R7 and R8 to 10kOhms. You also need to change R5 and R6 to 150 Ohms because there is too low current available for the LEDs.

I do not see having 1k base resistor a problem, any normal GPIO should be able to drive it, and 1k for LED should still make some visible light ( unless they are blue/white LEDs).
