LED does not blink when transmitting/receiving UART
I constructed the circuit as shown in the picture (I omitted the unnecessary parts)
I expected the LED to blink when the UART transmits and receives, but the LED is always on.
Is something wrong with my circuit?


Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/718147/communication-does-not-occur-when-connecting-an-led-to-the-uart-line

It's easier to see an LED that blinks 'on' when it is off than an LED that blinks 'off' when it is on. So you could reverse the logic (use a PNP transistor  as below) so the LED is on for the input low.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A better (but more complex) solution would be to use a retriggerable one-shot such as 74HC123 to stretch the pulses to something like 100ms.
They are even available cut down to 50% (single rather than dual) and in tiny packages.

Another variation that can work well is to use a red/green LED which is wired so the red LED will be on when the line is driven to a marking state, the green LED will be on when driven to a spacing state, and neither will be on--at least not very brightly--if the line is floating.

No there is nothing wrong. That is the expected operation of your circuit.
The LED will be on during logic high idle when nothing is transmitted, and turns/blinks off momentarily when something is transmitted and there is a logic low level.
If you use a high baud rate you simply might not see that the LED turns/blinks off, unless you send a long continuous sequence of zero bytes.
Also the transistor may just be slow to come out of saturation and turn off with just a 10 kohm base resistor pulling it low.
